# Jquery Button Click not displaying on td

Tags: jquery

I have  a column Additional Info . There is  a button on each  element.On click of  a button I have to show contents on td and hide that button on each td.But I cannot display info on second td.How to iterate through each td and show content on click of button for each td element when data is coming from mysql.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("btn_click").click(function(event) {
        $(".addButton:eq(0)").hide();
        //hide button    
        $("#showDiv").show();
        //show contents on the div
    });
});
```

Comment: I did this: for(var i=0;i<=tdCount;i++){
              alert(i);
              $(".addButton:eq(i)").hide();     
              $("#addInf.addInfo:eq(i)").show();
              }

Comment: Might be a typo: `$("btn_click")` missing `.` or `#`

Comment: missing '#'(id selector) or '.'(class selector) in btn_click

Answer (score 0):

You should look out for your use of IDs and CLASSes. jQuery will usually break when you have multiple IDs with the same name. If there is no other code conflicting with the above snippet, then changing `$("#showDiv").show();` to `$(".showDiv").show();` and also changing the html elements to correspond to this should solve your problem.

Also lookout for the click binding ( `$("btn_click").click`), you should probably change `btn_blick` to `.btn_click` (class selector, as btn_click is not a valid html tag by default).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how to iterate through a HTML collection of elements with jQuery.

You use the .each() function, example:

```
$(".selector").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   //do something
   element.hide();
});
```

You can use .on() to delegate events to a collection too

```
$(".selector > div").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
});
```